# The minimal group with Fitting length three

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group with Fitting lengt $3$ i.e

$$e< F_1< F_2 < F_3=G$$ and $F(G)=F_1$ and $\bar {F_2}=F(G/F_1)$.

If every proper subgroup of $G$ and every non-trivial quatient of $G$ has fitting lengt at most $2$ then can we say that $F_i/F_{i-1}$ is abelian ? Or What can we say in that case ?

Comment: You should probably replace $\le$ by $<$. Why length $3$ in particular? Is there a corresponding result for Fitting length $2$?

Comment: @DerekHolt: Yes. If $G$ is of the fitting lengt $2$ such that ecery proper subgroup and quatient is nilpotent then $F(G)$ is an elemantary abelian $p$ group and $G/F(G)$ is an elemantary abelian $q$ group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found an example in which $F_2/F_1$ is not abelian. This is $\mathtt{SmallGroup}(216,153)$ (in GAP or Magma), and it has the structure $3^2.Q_8.3$. So $F_1$ is elementary abelian of order $9$, $F_2/F_1 = Q_8$ and $|F_3/F_2|=3$.

I expect you can say something. I would conjecture that $F_1$ and $F_3/F_2$ have to be abelian, but proving it could be non-trivial.

Answer (score 2):

These arguments may prove your conjecture,

$F(G)/\Phi(G)=F(G/\Phi(G))$ hence we can assume that $\Phi(G)=1$. Since, $\Phi(G)\geq \Phi(F_1)$ we have $\Phi(F_1)=1$. Hence $F_1$ is a abelian group.

If $F_3/F_2$ is not abelian we can find characteristic subgroup $\bar C < F_3/F_2$. Then $F_2<C<F_3$ and $C$ is charrecteristic in $G$. $F(C)\geq F_1$ and $F(C)$ is also normal in $G$. Hence, $F(C)=F_1$. As $C$ must have nilpotent with lengt $2$,  $C/F(C)=C/F_1$ is nilpotent. Then, $C/F_1\leq F_2/F_1$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: That looks good!